# Vercel 404 page not found when requesting a page using vite+ts

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel

So i am trying vite and typescript, the website is fine in development but when i deployed it to vercel, it gave me:

> 404: NOT_FOUND
> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword

I dont think its because of my routing as it worked great in dev. Here is vercel's deployment log if it can help:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Security Policy, that is, [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) is a measure of defense for your website from XSS (cross-site-scripting) or data injection attacks, protecting it from referring to outside sources that are considered to be unsafe. CSP is either defined in a `meta` tag, such as

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';" />
```

It may also be set as a response header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy

The first thing you need to do in order to figure out the solution is to find out whether it's a response header or a meta tag in your case. If it's a response header, then you will need to look into your server settings or other resources that define response headers for your request.

If it's a meta tag, then you will need to detect where it is being generated.

Anyways, the error tells you that

> 404: NOT_FOUND
> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword

This means that you have a CSP for `script-src` which is

```
 "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'"
```

If you have some other `script`, look into its source and the solution will probably be as simple as changing the CSP to allow that other source.

The fact that this did not happen locally is a big clue that suggests that CSP is defined in a different manner on the server from your local, so it may be a server-setting or an unversioned code that defines it.